# Does PySpark only work on a single drive?

Tags: python, pyspark, windows-10

I have installed Spark on Windows 10 and have set the following user environment variables:

```
HADOOP_HOME = D:\spark\winutils
SPARK_HOME = D:\spark
```

PySpark behaves correctly when invoked from the C drive. I.e., I get the following:

```
(py35) C:\Users\tfovid>pyspark
Python 3.5.3 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, May 15 2017, 10:43:23) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
17/08/18 14:24:15 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/08/18 14:24:20 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.0
      /_/

Using Python version 3.5.3 (default, May 15 2017 10:43:23)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
```

However, when I invoke PySpark from the D drive, I get the following error:

```
(py35) D:\>pyspark
Python 3.5.3 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, May 15 2017, 10:43:23) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
17/08/18 14:23:21 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\spark\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "D:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o22.sessionState.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$reflect(SparkSession.scala:981)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:109)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$reflect(SparkSession.scala:978)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog':
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState$.org$apache$spark$sql$internal$SharedState$$reflect(SharedState.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.<init>(SharedState.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sharedState$1.apply(SparkSession.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sharedState$1.apply(SparkSession.scala:101)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sharedState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sharedState(SparkSession.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.<init>(SessionState.scala:157)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.<init>(HiveSessionState.scala:32)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState$.org$apache$spark$sql$internal$SharedState$$reflect(SharedState.scala:166)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:264)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:366)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.<init>(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:65)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: ---------
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:192)
        ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: ---------
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(SessionState.java:612)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:554)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:508)
        ... 40 more


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\spark\bin\..\python\pyspark\shell.py", line 43, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder\
  File "D:\spark\python\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 179, in getOrCreate
    session._jsparkSession.sessionState().conf().setConfString(key, value)
  File "D:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "D:\spark\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 79, in deco
    raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: "Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':"
```

Why does this happen? Is there a way to have PySpark work seamlessly on both drives? Note that both `HADOOP_HOME` and `SPARK_HOME` actually lead to the D drive. (Python works on both drives and is installed with the Anaconda distribution version 3-4.4.0.)

Comment: have you tried to run that from a _subdirectory_ of D drive?